# Facebook Login - WordPress Integration without plugin

Tags: facebook, wordpress, authentication, workflow, registration

**What is the workflow involved in Login with Facebook on WordPress ?**

I understand that this question has been asked several times, but none of the previous threads have the answer I'm looking for.

I have a working knowledge of OAuth 2.0 that Facebook currently uses and I'm familiar with the WordPress API. What I need to know is how does one use the data they get from the OAuth 2.0 to implement a register/login function in WordPress.

Is there a function to "log in" a user if the email id is provided ? Or to register a user based on the email id, first name, last name, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[wp_create_user](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user) take username password and email, to create a new user,

Instead if you want to get it by email you can use [get_user_by](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_by)

You can find more at the users and authors section of wordpress codex

Comment: how do I login a user if I have username and password ?

Comment: you can use [wp_signon](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon) passing the credentials. Worpress [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference#User_and_Author_Functions) under user & authors section have everything well written with examples :)